# Doing differentiation

Tags: calculus

$$y=4x^2+3x+7.$$ Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$

$$y+dy = 4(x+dx)^2 + 3(x+dx) + 7$$

$$y+dy = 4x^2 + 4dx^2 + 8xdx + 3x + 3dx + 7$$

$$dy = 4dx^2 + 8xdx + 3dx ( y = 4x^2 + 3x + 7 \text{ are cancelled} )$$

$$dy = dx(8x + 3)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 8x + 3$$

where does the$ 4dx^2$ go? Why is $4dx^2$ is neglected?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and write complete sentences.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep the second order term, but after dividing by $\Delta x$, and take limit to $0$, it vanishes.

$$\Delta y = 4\Delta x^2 + 8x\Delta x + 3\Delta x$$

$$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = 4\Delta x + 8x + 3$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} 4\Delta x + 8x + 3 = 8x+3$$

Remark: I change your notation so that I can write $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$